# design-pattern libraries ready-to-use?

Tags: php, design-patterns, frameworks, symfony1

symfony has released some of their [components](http://components.symfony-project.org/) free to use outside the framework.

i have used the event dispatcher and dependency injection...they are awesome!

i wonder if there are other components/libraries (from other frameworks etc) that in the same way help you manage various design patterns?

eg. decorator, facade, singleton, chain of commands etc.

i think symfony is on the right path, simplifying the usage of design patterns.

are there any other components out there doing the same?

thanks

Comment: Design Patterns are already as *abstract* as can be. Implementing a component library using Design Patterns is making it *concrete*.

Comment: okay...lets say it simplifies the usage of design patterns?...and Gordon...u r everywhere...u read all posts?

Comment: no, I'm just stalking you ;) j/k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/) takes this approach to the extreme as the entire framework is broken down into components which can be used on their own.